# ASP.NET Update Panel - Required Field Validator fires for AutoPostBack DropDownList even though CausesValidation = false

Tags: asp.net, validation, updatepanel

I'm having an issue where a required field validator flashes on the screen when the dropdown list it's attached to does a partial postback on change.

Essentially the page is a form where the user selects from the 1st dropdownlist and that populates a second dropdownlist. They then select from the 2nd dropdownlist. Then when the user has selected both they hit the submit button and that validates both dropdowns.

Both dropdowns are in the validationgroup that the submit button uses. I've added CausesValidation="false" to the dropdownlist but the validator still flashes. Sample code below...

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="MyAppScriptManager" runat="server"
        EnablePartialRendering="true"
        EnableCdn="true" />

        <div class="chat">

                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="NewBookingUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>

                                    <div id="FreelancerDiv" class="collapse show">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="FreelancerDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                                                        CausesValidation="false"
                                                        class="custom-select form-control form-control-lg">
                                                        <asp:ListItem Value=" " Text="Choose the freelancer for your booking." />
                                                        <asp:ListItem Value="Good" Text="Good selection." />
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                </div>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="FreelancerRequired" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"
                                                    ControlToValidate="FreelancerDropDownList"
                                                    ValidationGroup="RequestBookingValidationGroup"
                                                    ErrorMessage="&nbsp;Required&nbsp;"
                                                    CssClass="alert-danger" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                 
                                    <div id="ServiceDiv" class="collapse show" runat="server">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ServiceDropDownList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                                                        CausesValidation="false"
                                                        class="custom-select form-control form-control-lg">
                                                        <asp:ListItem Value=" " Text="Choose the service for your booking." />
                                                        <asp:ListItem Value="Good" Text="Good selection." />
                                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                                </div>
                                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ServiceRequired" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"
                                                    ControlToValidate="ServiceDropDownList"
                                                    ValidationGroup="RequestBookingValidationGroup"
                                                    ErrorMessage="&nbsp;Required&nbsp;"
                                                    CssClass="alert-danger" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                               
                                <button id="RequestBooking" runat="server" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="button" onserverclick="RequestBooking_Click" validationgroup="RequestBookingValidationGroup">
                                    Request Booking
                                </button>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>

        </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JobesK thanks for Enabled=false tip that helped :)

I disabled the validators in markup and then enabled them in javascript in the submit button...

```
                ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%=FreelancerRequired.ClientID%>'), true);
                                        ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('<%=ServiceRequired.ClientID%>'), true);
                                        Page_ClientValidate("RequestBookingValidationGroup");
```

Comment: Glad it was helpful. Curious how are you calling validation? The button click event should look something like: Page.Validate("RequestBookingValidationGroup"); if(Page.IsValid){ // click code here }

Answer (score 0):

You can enable or disable (enabled=true or enabled=false) the required field validators on the postback (and/or in the markup or page load event). Believe it's defaulted to enabled which is why its firing.

Comment: I don't think you've read the question. "Then when the user has selected everything they hit the submit button at the bottom which validates everything". If I just disabled the validator then the submit button wouldn't validate

Comment: I read it, everything is being validated and it sounds like you DONT want a validator to validate on postback? If not you could rephrase the post for clarity so I understand it better.

Comment: That's correct, when selecting the dropdown it does as partial post back and the validator briefly flashes, but it posts back ok and the validator then disappears. I want the validators to fire only when the submit button is clicked.

Comment: The button click event should look something like: Page.Validate("RequestBookingValidationGroup"); if(Page.IsValid){ // click code here }